# Add constraint using migration - yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I would like to add constraints to my table user : `username => unique, password => NOT NULL`.

I would like to make it properly using migration and I could't find how.

I can drop the table and create it again with the constraint or directly in command line but i will lose data.

I looked at the documentation here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration but didn't find anything.

I m using yii framework and a MySQL db.

SOLUTION :

```
class m150311_075741_update_users extends CDbMigration
{
  public function up()
  {
      $this->alterColumn('user', 'username', 'varchar(255) unique');
      $this->alterColumn('user', 'password', 'varchar(255) not null');
  }

  public function down()
  {
      $this->alterColumn('user', 'username', 'varchar(255) unique');
      $this->alterColumn('user', 'password', 'varchar(255)');
  }
}
```

Comment: Except constraint you dont have to change any thing in table?

Comment: Yes only constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [alterColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#alterColumn-detail) method.

```
alterColumn('MyTable', 'username', 'varchar(32) unique');
alterColumn('MyTable', 'password', 'varchar(32) not null');
```

Note: You need to respecify the full column structure again you can't just add the new additions on to it, so you might want to change varchar(32) stuff to the current structure.

Comment: How are you using it now?

Comment: I add it using MySQL prompt :/ didn t find better solution.
I could have make a script which save data, drop, create the table and then add data again but it s complicated for nothing. It s just 2 command lines.

Comment: The code I posted should work fine, only reason why it wouldn't is if you didn't use it correctly.

Comment: My bad it worked well, i don t know why it failed the first time.
Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Then export your table for only data not with data and structure both.
Once you have exported your table with data.

Delete your table and make same table with constraints added.

Now import your exported table.

DONE !!!!!

Comment: This way is the easiest, i was just wondering if i could add constraint without doing all this. But if i can't i would do this.